# Аргументы методов в C# по ссылке или по значению?

Tags: c#, clr, теория

Насколько я знаю в сишарпе аргументы передаются по значению. Но тогда я не понимаю вот чего. Я сейчас смотрю код, в котором присутствует такой метод:

```
public static string GetRequest(string Url, string UserAgent = "", CookieDictionary Cookies = null, ProxyType ProxyProto = ProxyType.None, string ProxyString = "")
{
    ...

    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = request.Get(Url);
        Cookies = response.Cookies;
        response_html = response.ToString();
    } 

}
```

То есть он получает куки, а потом добавляет в них те что получены из ответа.
Если переменные передаются по значению то так по-идее работать не должно, но я проверил вот так:

```
CookieDictionary cookies = new CookieDictionary();
string url = "http://mail.ru";
string resp = Web.GetRequest(url, "", cookies, Web.ProxyType.HTTP, "127.0.0.1:8888");
resp = Web.GetRequest(url, "", cookies, Web.ProxyType.HTTP, "127.0.0.1:8888");
```

При втором запросе передаются куки, которые получены при первом. Кроме того в методе я пробовал добавлять свои куки через Cookies.Add() и они присутствовали в следующих вопросах. Почему это работает?

Comment: Вы неправильно знаете. Ссылочные типы передаются по ссылке, а значимые по значению.

Comment: а еще если переменная переданная в метод является статической то в методе ее можно случайно перетереть другими данными, в остальных случаях передаются копии объектов, исключением будут переменные помеченные `ref` или `out`

Comment: @vitidev, а как определить какой тип к какой группе принадлежит?

Comment: значимые типы наследуются от ValueType, а ссылочные от Object.

Comment: @vitidev вы тоже неправильно говорите. Передача по ссылке - это `ref`.нельзя говорить что все ссылочные типы передаются по ссылке.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы правы.  передаются аргументы по значению, но значением ссылочного типа является именно ссылка. но при этом копируется указатель, а не само значение. Автор вопроса считал, что передаются копии объектов, а не указателей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В C# действительно аргументы передаются по значению. Вопрос только, что это за аргументы.

Если это аргументы — числа или похожие объекты (они называются типами-значениями), то они передаются таки как есть — передаётся их *копия*.

А если аргументы — объекты классов (они называются ссылочными типами), то по значению передаётся **ссылка** (то есть как бы указатель, если вы знакомы с C) на объект, а не копия самого объекта. По копии ссылки объект доступен точно так же, как и по оригиналу, и это тот же самый объект.

Почему это сделано так? Дело в том, что не все объекты можно просто склонировать. И даже если это можно, что делать со ссылками на другие объекты, которые содержит данный объект? Клонировать все внутренние объекты? Это слишком долго и слишком сложно (например, что делать, если ссылки выстраиваются в цикл?). А если внутренние объекты не клонировать, возникает та же проблема: сам объект копируется, а внутренние подобъекты всё равно передадутся по ссылке.

Comment: Да, но как определить какой объект к какой категории относится все-таки?

Comment: @АлександрПушкин: Очень просто. Те, которые определены с ключевым словом `class` — ссылочные типы. Те, которые определены с ключевым словом `struct` — типы-значения.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин: Базовые типы (`int`, `char`, etc.), кроме `string` — типы-значения, `string` — ссылочный тип.

Comment: @VladD Базовые типы (int, char, etc.) - если пойти к описанию видно что это те же struct

Comment: @Grundy: Так и есть, но это продвинутые знания :)

Comment: @АлександрПушкин _"как определить какой объект к какой категории относится все-таки?"_ -- у объекта вызовите .GetType().IsClass и/или .GetType().IsValueType

Answer (score 0):

В отличие от некоторых языков программирования, C # имеет две разновидности типов данных: для значения и для ссылки. Если производительность приложения имеет существенное значение или есть заинтересованность в том, как C# управляет данными и памятью, важно знать различия между этими типами.

Если в объявлении переменной используется один из основных встроенных типов данных или определенная пользователем структура данных, значит мы имеем дело с типом значения. Исключение составляет тип данных `string`, который является ссылочным типом.

Структуры и перечисления в C# так же являются значимыми типами(value types). По этому не рекомендуется использовать в качестве аргументов слишком большие структуры, так как это может сказаться на производительности.

На счет строк рекомендую прочитать например [эту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165597/) статейку, т.к. со строками не все так очевидно, как могло бы показаться.

Comment: То есть я могу передать в метод строку и изменить ее внешнее значение внутри метода? Так вроде бы не получалось.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин можете, пометив ее как `out`

Comment: @Dmitry, но в ответе Мстислава написано что строка тоже ссылочный тип и получается помечать ничего не надо тогда.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин, в метод уйдет копия строки

Comment: @АлександрПушкин строка - особый тип. он ссылочный, но еще иммутабельный (внутренняя реализация)